# string literal and template parameter

Tags: c++

```
void p(const char(&a)[5]) {
  std::cout << type_name<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
}
```

I understand p("abc") would work.
what if I made the template like this

```
template <typename T>
void p(T& a) {
  std::cout << type_name<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
}
```

If I did the same thing, which is p("abc"), then what would T be? since a is surrounded by bracket p(const char(&a)[5]) I am confused.

Comment: You can force a compilation error to get the compiler to tell you - `In instantiation of 'void p(T&) [with T = const char [4]]'` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/7dWMjrd7n

Comment: substituting T with const char [4] will give void p(const char [4]& a) but it causes compile error

Comment: void p(T& a) {
  std::cout << type_name<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
}   p(3); why isnt this working?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you get an error you didn't expect, you should generally post the error itself, alongside any thing it mentions that you've written. If you can post a simple reproducer on a website such as godbolt too and link it here, even better!

Comment: You can't determine a type by string substitution. If `T` is "array of four `const char`s" (`const char[4]`), `T&` is "reference to array of four `const char`s" (`const char(&)[4]`). An entirely different problem is that you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. That has nothing to so with templates, though.